# Always my last row of database is not showing in alertdialog

Tags: android, baseadapter

I am  developing a android App where i have to show my data on customize alert dialog from data base. This is my database[image]

I am trying to show all these data on alert-dialog a by follwing code

```
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Position " + position);
    int _id = 0;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    OrderViewHolder orderViewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        orderViewHolder = new OrderViewHolder();

        switch (type) {
        case TYPE_STATUS:

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_header, null);
            orderViewHolder.setTvTitle((TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.category));

            break;

        case TYPE_ITEM:
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.order_list_row, null);
            orderViewHolder.setTvTitle((TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.orderTitle));
            orderViewHolder.setTvPrice((TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.orderPrice));
            orderViewHolder.setIvDelete((ImageButton) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.deleteOrder));
            // orderViewHolder.setIvDelete((ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.deleteOrder).setLayoutParams(params))
            break;
        }

        convertView.setTag(orderViewHolder);

    } else {
        orderViewHolder = (OrderViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (position == 0) {
        if (starterCount != 0) {
            orderViewHolder.getTvTitle().setText("");
            // orderViewHolder.getTvTitle().setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.tab_starters_menu_on);
            orderViewHolder.getTvTitle().setTextColor(R.color.Black);
            orderViewHolder.getTvTitle().setTextSize(12);
            orderViewHolder.getTvTitle().setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
          orderViewHolder.getTvTitle().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tt111);
            orderViewHolder.getTvTitle().setHeight(20); 
            orderViewHolder.getTvTitle().setWidth(100);
            /*
             * RestaurantHome.setFontTextViewTahoma(OrderListAdapter,
             * orderViewHolder.getTvTitle());
             */
        }    
        else {    
            orderViewHolder.getTvTitle().setText(" ");
            orderViewHolder.getTvTitle().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);   
        }

    }    


    if ((position !=0))

    {        
        System.out.println(" position vlue   : "+position);
        if (oStarterCursor.moveToPosition(position-1)) {
            String title = oStarterCursor.getString(oStarterCursor.getColumnIndex("item_name"));
            System.out.println( " value of title "+title);
            String price = oStarterCursor.getString(oStarterCursor.getColumnIndex("Item_cost"));  
            System.out.println( " value of price "+price);

            _id = oStarterCursor.getInt(oStarterCursor
                    .getColumnIndex("_id"));
            if (title != null) {
                title = title.trim();  
                orderViewHolder.getTvTitle().setText(title);   
                orderViewHolder.getTvTitle().setTextColor(R.color.black);
                orderViewHolder.getTvTitle().setTextSize(12);
                orderViewHolder.getTvTitle().setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
                orderViewHolder.getTvTitle().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            }

            if (price != null) {
                price = price.trim();
                orderViewHolder.getTvPrice().setText(price + ".00");
                orderViewHolder.getTvTitle().setTextColor(R.color.black);
                orderViewHolder.getTvTitle().setTextSize(12);
                orderViewHolder.getTvTitle().setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
                orderViewHolder.getTvTitle().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);    


            }
            _id = oStarterCursor.getInt(oStarterCursor.getColumnIndex("_id")); 


        }


                    convertView.setTag(R.id.orderTitle, _id);
        if (orderViewHolder.getIvDelete() != null) {
            orderViewHolder.getIvDelete().setTag(R.id.orderTitle, _id);
        }
        // _id =
        // oStarterCursor.getInt(oStarterCursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
    }

    //}

    return convertView;}
```

I am going to post my order_list_row.xml file.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="100sp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#fff" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/deleteOrder"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:onClick="clickHandler"
    android:src="@drawable/icon_close" >
</ImageButton>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/orderTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_margin="4sp"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="16dp" >
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/orderPrice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4sp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/deleteOrder"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/orderTitle"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="16dp" >
</TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But it is not showing my last data in my database.[image]

As you can see by my screen shot last data is not showing form database. Why fanta is not showing ?  Always last row is showing in alertdialog from database.What is logical issue in my code i can't understand ? Most probably it is mistake of my logic but where it is i can't find . I hope  i am able to explain my problem to all my well-wisher . Please help me . Thanks in advance to all

Comment: Total amount showing correct 663??

Comment: No..it is not issue for will manage total amount...issue is in where is my last row of database?

Comment: but since you are in the getview method, why dont u use the position provided by the getview method ?? Better still use a cursor adpater or a simple cursor adapter.

Comment: please check table data whether you are getting full rows or not??

Comment: @Indra..I check last row data is not coming in cursor. Why it is not coming i couldn't understand. Although all data is showing except last row of database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solve my issue. Thanks to all who suggest me to solve this issue.

```
   public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d(TAG, "GetCount "+starterCount);
    return starterCount +1 ;
}
```

And

```
   if ((position !=0)&& (position != starterCount + 1))    

    {     
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

i would like to know why are u passing `position -1` as param to movetoPosition method
just pass `position` .. 
i think according to your approach last element is never being read !!

Comment: ohh sorry i didn't read that its in getView() method let me edit my ans

Comment: I used position-1 because when position is at one then retrieve data at 0 cursor level

Comment: so if ur max position is 9 (0 - 9) and your cursor count is also 9 then 9-1 = 8 and your last element is never going to be read !!

Comment: @r4jv007..Thanks....what you think  if used nested if else (oStarterCursor.moveToPosition(position-1)) and (oStarterCursor.moveToLast()) both work for me?

Comment: @r4j007.. your suggestion help me..but how i implement ?